# Problema al insertar dato en base de datos android studio

Tags: java, android

El problema que tengo es que si intento insertar un dato vacío la aplicación falla y no se porque. Con cualquier numero va bien pero si lo dejo vacío falla

Tengo la base datos:

```
 public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String nombre, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, nombre, factory, version);
        }
        @Override

            dr.execSQL("create table pedido3(lugar integer primary key , cantidad integer, producto text)");

 @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase dr, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

           dr.execSQL("drop table if exists pedido3");
           dr.execSQL("create table pedido3(lugar integer primary key , cantidad integer, producto text)");
```

aqui inserto el dato:

```
 public void altamesa3 (View view){
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,
                "cocina3", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase br = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        String lugar = "1";
        EditText numero=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.naguamesa3);
        String cantidad = numero.getText().toString();
        String producto = tv1.getText().toString();

        ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
        registro.put("lugar",lugar);
        registro.put("cantidad", cantidad);
        registro.put("producto", producto);

        Cursor fila = br.rawQuery(
                "select cantidad,producto from pedido3 where lugar=1", null);
        if (fila.moveToFirst()) {

            int cant=Integer.parseInt(cantidad);
            if(cant>0) {
                br.update("pedido3", registro, "lugar=1", null);
            }
        }
        else{
            br.insert("pedido3",null,registro);
        }
```

Comment: en que campo insertas un dato vacio y falla? , en que elemento recibes ese dato?

Comment: Prueba si haciendo el INSERT (no desde tu app) de alguna aplicacion que te permite usar el insert) se logra, si aún así "falla" entonces no es propiamente desde Android Studio. Si el dato puede ir en blanco tal vez requieran modifcar la tabla a fin que los acepte y sería un valor NULL no un string que recibiria para vacio. Indica la Base de Datos que usas; no veo en los crete que hay el código el tipo de dato que corresponde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que comentas es al recibir el dato `cantidad` en el `EditText`, si este esta vacio, al intentar insertar marca error:

```
   EditText numero=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.naguamesa3);
   String cantidad = numero.getText().toString();
```

Puedes validar para asegurar que la variable tenga un valor default al ser insertada:

```
 String cantidad = if(numero.getText().toString();
 if (cantidad == null || cantidad.length() == 0){
        cantidad = "0";
    }
```

Con esto obtendras un valor de cantidad igual a cero si el `EditText` no contiene valor.

---

En realidad la aplicación se cierra porque estas realizando una conversion a entero de un valor no numerico, esto cuando cantidad tiene valor vacio o null:

```
int cant=Integer.parseInt(cantidad);
```

lo que tienes que realizar es validar el caso en que cantidad no sea numerico:

```
 //int cant=Integer.parseInt(cantidad);   
int cant = 0;
 try {  
     cant = Integer.parseInt(cantidad);  
  }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){  
    cant = 0;
  }
```

Comment: aja pero lo que quiero es que quede null para poder jugar con el valor 0

Comment: Quieres cambiar cantidad a null cuando el EditText es vacio? te refieres a que deseas manipular valores nulos en tu aplicación, no creo que sea la forma correcta.

Comment: quiero poder diferenciar entre meter un dato vacio (null) y meter 0

Comment: Cuando es null, cambiar el valor de cantidad a 0 ¿

Comment: no. que null sea una cosa y 0 otra

Comment: Sinceramente no entiendo que deseas realizar, **el titulo de tu pregunta indica que solo quieres saber porque falla la aplicaciòn cuando insertas un dato vacio "El problema que tengo es que si intento insertar un dato vacio la aplicacion falla y no se porque. Con cualquier numero va bien pero si lo dejo vacio falla"**.  Quieres diferenciar entre meter un dato vacio (null) y meter 0, entonces ya sabes cual es la causa por la que tu aplicaciòn falla?

Comment: a ver quiero saber como puedo meter un dato null, pq si le doy a enviar el dato sin meter ninguna cifra la aplicacion crashea

Comment: Agreguè la razon por la que se cierra tu aplicación y como evitarlo. Solo recuerda que si insertas un null en un campo entero no es una buena practica, esto porque por ejemplo podrìas necesitar un query donde se obtuvieran los registros con cantidad = 0. @miklotov

Answer (score 1):

Tu tienes `lugar` definido como integer primary key, eso significa que en tu tabla sirve como ROWID. Supongo que quieres dejar el dato `lugar` vacío para que SQL te genera una entrada autogenerada (AUTOINCREMENT).

Para lograr eso deberias hacer una de dos cosas:

- **no** asignar `lugar` a tus `ContentValues` o
- assignar `null` al key "lugar" de tus `ContentValues`

En tu código veo solamente que asignas "1" a lugar (y lo asignas como String).

Tu **no** puedes asignar el mismo valor dos veces a un ROWID/ (integer primary key).

En todo caso deberías considerar usar un `int` o `long` en las variables de tu código para el campo `lugar`. SQLite integer puede contener valores hasta 64bit, que corresponde a long en Java.

Para encontrar tu error deberías además hacer una depuración y revisar si te sale una excepción que te puede indicar donde el `insert` falla.

Si quieres agregar valores `integer` o `null` tienes que evitar que tu columna se interpreta como ROWID. Eso puedes hacer en varias maneras:

- declara la columna como `INT` o `BIGINT` (en vez de `INTEGER`) o
- declara la tabla con `WITHOUT ROWID`

Comment: el lugar esta ya asignado y esta bien, lo que quiero es poder meter la cantidad como null, es decir, dejarlo vacio. Quiero que se pueda meter null o un numero (incluyendo el 0 entre los numeros)

Comment: Entonces lee la respuesta de nuevo. Si quieres colocar null y 0+, no puedes usar `primary key` con la columna, o SQLite interpreta la columna como rowid, aclaro  más en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por las respuestas. He conseguido hacer algo parecido a lo que quería asique problema solucionado. Un saludo